# Python, как цикл for переделать в генератор списка?

Tags: python

Решил переделать все свои циклы for в генераторы списков. Но попался цикл посложнее и я впал в ступор, а в сети как назло все примеры максимально простые.
Пожалуйста объясните, как должен выглядеть подобный генератор.

```
C = [[[1 for y in range(3)] for x in range(3)] for i in range(12)]

A = [0 for x in range(12)]

for i in range(12):
    for x in range(3):
        for y in range(3):
            if C[i][x][y] != 0:
                A[i] = A[i] + 1

print(A)

[9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9]

# мой говнокод с ошибкой
A = [A[i]+1 for y in range(3) for x in range(3) for i in range(12) if C[i][x][y] != 0]
```

Comment: А зачем переделывать? Генератор списка хорош, когда кода мало

Comment: говорят, что в большинстве случаев генераторы работают быстрее цикла for, да смотрятся приятнее

Comment: @ПавелZZZ различие в скорости обычно незначительное и далеко не всегда в лучшую сторону.

Comment: @ПавелZZZ, вот `[0 for x in range(12)]` смотрится приятно, а `[sum(1 for row in lst for x in row if x != 0) for lst in C]` (extrn, без обид, ладно? :)) нет :) Код чаще читается, чем пишется. Поэтому, лучше писать так, чтобы было сразу понятно. Кроме того, не следует заниматься преждевременной оптимизацией. Вот когда будут проседания в алгоритме и точно сможете определить, что из-за цикла, то все-равно не будете генераторы использовать, т.к. есть `numpy`, либо реализация через сишный код, что будете вызывать

Comment: @gil9red никаких обид, но мнения вашего я не разделяю :) Такой код может получиться настоящим минным полем как для читающего, так и для пишущего. Например, `[0 for x in range(12)]` я бы заменил на `[0 for _ in C]` сразу по нескольким причинам.

Comment: @extrn, это был пример, а так, оно рефакторится в `[0 for _ in range(12)]`, а после в `[0] * 12` :)

Comment: @gil9red Я же сказал, по нескольким причинам. Одна из них использование константы `12`  Мой вариант, или же `[0] * len(C)`, позволит избежать потенциальных ошибок в будущем.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Списковое включение](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) это чистая функциональная конструкция. Т.е. реализовать с помощью него алгоритм, который в процессе модифицирует данные в общем случае не получится (или крайне нежелательно).

Но почти любой такой алгоритм можно привести к подходящему виду.

```
A = [sum(1 for row in lst for x in row if x != 0) for lst in C]
```

Comment: Можно без `if` сделать: `A = [sum(x != 0 for row in lst for x in row) for lst in C]`

Comment: @insolor Можно, но это был осознанный выбор :) Мне кажется, функциональное решение должно быть не максимально коротким, а в первую очередь хорошо читаемым (может быть не для полного новичка в фп, но для человека с минимальной подготовкой).

Comment: Читаемость - вещь субъективная. Мне кажется, в моем варианте наоборот сразу видно, что мы считаем все не равные нулю значения, а в вашем варианте if еще нужно увидеть, на сразу понятно почему единицы суммируются.

Comment: @insolor Согласен, увы в python нет подсчета элементов по предикату, как в scala, например, и `sum` - вынужденная мера. Но то, что в python `issubclass(bool, int)` знают даже не все более менее подготовленные программисты, и результат очевиден не для всех. Хотя, признаюсь, раньше я и сам отдавал предпочтение такому подходу.

Comment: в данном кокретном случае (по ощущениям) можно обойтись не sum спереди, а count сзади ))ну или  ........................... len(x != 0 for row in lst for x in row)

Comment: @VasylKolomiets ни `len` ни `.count` не работают с итераторами, придется создавать промежуточные списки, так `len([0 for row in lst for x in row if x != 0])` или так `[x != 0 for row in lst for x in row].count(True)`